# How do I change the media player datasource?

Tags: android, media-player

How do I change the media player datasource without resetting it when it is already playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its possible (or perhaps I haven't come along anything like this yet),

Since it actively reads the data from the data-source, buffers small chunks of it, and then plays, thus it will not let you change it in the middle.